# How to compile Oracle DB Object via Java application?

Tags: oracle, plsql, compilation

I would like to create an java application, which able to compile the DB object to DB schema, such as compile procedure, package, function, trigger, table creation/altering, can I run that via callablestatement? Any suggestion to me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to open a SQL-Conntection and run compile-commands:

```
ALTER PACKAGE mySchema.MyPackage COMPILE;

ALTER VIEW myScham.MyView COMPILE;
```

etc..

There are multiple ways to open a connection and run commands. But this is another question i think.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it straightforward via JDBC API:

```
Connection connection = getConnection(); // implement this anyhow

// way 1
String createProc = "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc IS BEGIN NULL; END";
Statement stmt1 = connection.prepareStatement(createProc);
stmt1.execute();

// way 2
String alterCompilePkg = "ALTER PACKAGE my_package COMPILE";
Statement stmt2 = connection.createStatement();
stmt2.executeUpdate(alterCompilePkg);
```

The first and the second ways both are valid for executing DDL.
So you can execute any DDL statement. Look for [more examples](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/sql/jdbc-ddl-example/).
Do not forget to close statements after usage.